# multiple field and numeric sort

Tags: bash, sorting

List of files:

```
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndwr-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndwr-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndwr-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndwr-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqrd-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqrd-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqrd-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqrd-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqwr-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqwr-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqwr-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-seqwr-threads-8
```

I would like to sort them by mode (rndrd, rndwr etc.) and then number:

```
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrd-threads-16
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-1
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-4
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-8
sysbench-size-256M-mode-rndrw-threads-16
....
```

I've tried the following loop but it's sorting by number but I need sequence like 1,4,8,16:

```
$ for f in $(ls -1A); do echo $f; done | sort -t '-' -k 7n
```

EDIT:

Please note that numeric sort (-n) sort it by number (1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4...) but I need sequence like 1,4,8,16,1,4,8,16...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop is completely unnecessary as is the `-1` argument to `ls` when piping its output. This yields

```
ls -A | sort -t- -k 5,5 -k 7,7n
```

where the first key begins and ends at column 5 and the second key begins and ends at column 7 and is numeric.

Answer (score 5):

Sort by more columns:

```
sort -t- -k5,5 -k7n
```

Primary sort is by 5th column (and not the rest, that's why `5,5`), secondary sorting by number in the 7th column.

Comment: This command is accepted but seems to silently ignore the `n` (using GNU sort 8.20)